# Integer array as hashmap input

Tags: java

I am currently writing a program where I need a coordinate pair(2 integers) to have a boolean value. I was thinking I could use a hashmap to do this but I have no idea how I would do the constructor or use any of the methods.

Comment: So you're asking...how does one use a `HashMap`?

Comment: I think the is is something to do with generics

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Veeeeeeeeeery unspecific. Have you got any code? And an actual questinon would help this question to be more like a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you need to create a new Class, i.e. name it PairedIntegers, with two fields `Integer a`, `Integer b`. Then use this Class as a key to your Hashmap. Don't forget to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods